# HDFS block size and file size problems file smaller than block size

Tags: hdfs

I have a HDFS cluster running on several linux machines with default block size of 64MB, if I store a file of size 1MB, will it occupy 64MB storage on my linux machine?

Similarly, if I store a file of size 65MB, will it occupy two blocks of 64MB on my machine or one 64MB and 1MB blocks?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437853/how-does-hdfs-manage-block-size

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Hadoop : The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

> Unlike a filesystem for a single disk, a file in HDFS that is smaller than a single block does not occupy a full block’s worth of underlying storage.